# how to trim input string into key value

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, collections

For example, CA, California is the input.
The output should be:

You added CA, California
CA         - should be the key*
California - should be the value*

```
    Dim input As String = txtInput.Text.ToString

    List.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(* Trimmed input*))

    Output("You added: " + input)
    Output(tkey, tvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the input at ", " which would separate it into CA and California. You could then set key to be your first piece, and the value to be your second.

```
Dim splitInput as string() = input.split(", ") 'Break apart at ", "
Dim tKey as String = splitInput(0) 'Set key to first piece
Dim tValue as String = splitInput(1) 'Set value to second piece
```

Comment: how do i output the tkey and tvalue in other sub function, supposed that im using sub OutputStates() to output the CA, and California.

Comment: You would give `OutputStates()` parameters, like so: `Private Sub OutputStates(ByVal tkey as String, ByVal tValue as String)`. Then call like so: `OutputStates(tKey, tValue)`

Comment: i have show button, that calls OutputStates() but it gives me error that says "argument not specified for parameter tKey of public sub OutputStates(tKey as string, tValue as String)

Comment: Make sure you're doing `OutputStates(tKey, tValue)`, not just `OutputStates()`

Comment: Yes, ive done that, but still theres an error on the tkey and tvalue OutputStates(tKey, tValue)